# Ruby find User with specific Post contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
Class User 
  has_many :posts
end

Class Post
  belongs_to :users
end
```

I have a post's content and would like to find out if a user ever sent a post with the same content. I could find it out easily if I was only searching against a single user.

```
user.posts.exists?(content: params[:content])
```

I would like to look through all the users in the DB.

```
users = Users.all
users.posts # will not work NoMethodError: undefined method `posts' for #<Array:0x007fbe818fbd98>
```

I need either a `true` as soon as there is a single match or a `false` if there is no user with matching content, for all the posts posted from all the users.

I could always loop this in a block and get a result this way, is there a way of doing this in a single line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
posts = Post.where(content: params[:content])
users = User.find posts.map(&:user_id)
```

Or a shorter one:

```
users = User.find Post.where(content: params[:content]).pluck(:id)
```

Or if you just need to check whether a post (created by any user) with a given content exist:

```
Post.exists?(content: params[:content])
```